# How to create a hashMap of particular fields from RDD[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How to create a hashMap of particular fields from RDD[String] ?

```
  {
    count: 1,
    itemId: "1122334",
    country: {
        code: {
            preferred: "USA"
        },
        name: {
            preferred: "America"
        }
    },
    states: "50",
    self: {
        otherInfo: [

        ],
        preferred: "National Parks"
    },
    Rating: 4

    }

Ho do I get a hashmap maps which have {itemid , self.preferred} :

itemId : 1122334  self.preferred : "National Parks"
itemId : 1144444  self.preferred : "State Parks"
....
```

I tried this, its working but not efficient since I am converting to JSON Obj and doing the parse :

```
 val filteredMappingsList = countryMapping.filter(x=> {
    val jsonObj = new JSONObject(x)
    jsonObj.has("itemId") && jsonObj.get("itemId").toString.startsWith("11")

})

val finalMapping = filteredMappingsList.map(x=>{
    val jsonObj = new JSONObject(x);
    val itemId = jsonObj.get("itemId").toString()
    val preferred = jsonObj.getJSONObject("self").get("preferred ").toString()
    (itemId, preferred)
}).collectAsMap
```

Is there anyother way to do this efficiently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using one of the many JSON libraries to parse your data is probably still your best bet. However, it looks like you are parsing your strings to JSON twice, once in the filter and once in the map. I'm not sure if that's how it actually executes. But consider just parsing it once:

```
val result = countryMapping.map(x => newJSONObject(x)).
               filter(jsonObj => ...).
               map{jsonObj =>
                 ...
                 (itemId, preferred)
                 }.collectAsMap
```